# JSON Undefined node trying to parse

Tags: javascript, json

Trying to parse JSON and getting an UNDEFINED when I try to access one of the nodes. The first part of the JSON and the function are below

```
function loadmakes()
    {

    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "getedmunds.php",
    data:'id=1',
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        alert( data);       
        alert(data.makes); //<<<< **FAILS HERE Undefined** 

        for(var i in data.makes)
                {
                         $('#make').append('<option value=' + data.makes[i].id + '>' + data.makes[i].name + '</option>');
                }
    }, 
    error:function (){
        alert("Error calling makes");
        }
    });

}
```

This is the first lines of the JSON

```
{"makes":[{"id":200002038,"name":"Acura","niceName":"acura","models":[{"id":"Acura_ILX","name":"ILX","niceName":"ilx","years":[{"id":200471908,"year":2014}]},{"id":"Acura_ILX_Hybrid","name":"ILX Hybrid","niceName":"ilx-hybrid","years":[{"id":200493809,"year":2014}]},{"id":"Acura_MDX","name":"MDX","niceName":"mdx","years":[{"id":200465929,"year":2014}]},{"id":"Acura_RDX","name":"RDX","niceName":"rdx","years":[{"id":200467168,"year":2014}]},{"id":"Acura_RLX","name":"RLX","niceName":"rlx","years":[{"id":100539511,"year":2014}]},{"id":"Acura_TL","name":"TL","niceName":"tl","years":[{"id":200488448,"year":2014}]},{"id":"Acura_TSX","name":"TSX","niceName":"tsx","years":[{"id":200490517,"year":2014}]},{"id":"Acura_TSX_Sport_Wagon","name":"TSX Sport Wagon","niceName":"tsx-sport-wagon","years":[{"id":200673755,"year":2014}]}]},{"id":200001769,"name":"Aston Martin","niceName":"aston-martin","models":[{"id":"Aston_Martin_DB9","name":"DB9","niceName":"db9","years":[{"id":200473436,"year":2014}]},...
```

Comment: Pls post the result of console.log(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `data` isn't a parsed JSON object, it's a string. When you use AJAX, it returns a string.

You can do one of two things: one, jQuery provides a [`dataType` option for `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Simply provide the value `"json"` and jQuery/AJAX will automatically parse the result for you.

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // `data` is a javascript object now.
    }
});
```

You could also use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse `data` in success. This is practically what jQuery/AJAX does for you via the last solution, though.